# Apache axis 1.3 - Element with same name in wsdl

Tags: java, field, apache-axis

I have a SOAP service with following elements in wsdl file.(first one starts with lowercase 'i' and second one with uppercase 'I')

Field 1

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="inventoryOrganization" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Field 2

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="InventoryOrganization" nillable="true" type="tns2:ReceiptOfGoods_InventoryOrganization"/>
```

When I create the stub from this .wsdl, In the stub file I have

```
private java.lang.String inventoryOrganization;

private com.app.system.webservices.dataimport.generated.gr.service.data.ReceiptOfGoods_InventoryOrganization inventoryOrganization2;
```

And the generated XML fields are as below

```
<ns1:inventoryOrganization2 invalid="false">
    <ns1:guid>SAMPLE-ID</ns1:guid>
    <ns1:code>100001</ns1:code>
</ns1:inventoryOrganization2>

<ns1:InventoryOrganization xsi:type="xsd:string">SAMPLE-ID</ns1:InventoryOrganization>
```

What change should I do in the generated stub to communicate with this service. After some more research I hope, the custom serializer will be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was , In the generated class the field was mapped like

```
typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
elemField.setFieldName("inventoryOrganization");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://url/data", "InventoryOrganization"));
elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://url/data", "ReceiptOfGoods_InventoryOrganization"));
elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
elemField.setNillable(true);
```

It has to be changed to

```
typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
elemField.setFieldName("inventoryOrganization2");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://url/data", "InventoryOrganization"));
elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://url/data", "ReceiptOfGoods_InventoryOrganization"));
elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
elemField.setNillable(true);
```

In the automatically generated stub, it was mapped as `elemField.setFieldName("inventoryOrganization");` , instead of `elemField.setFieldName("inventoryOrganization2");`